# How to store a MySQL data in a variable in Android Studio?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio, wamp

I am new to Android Studio, and I have created a database in wamp server and now want to retrieve the data and store it in a variable in Android Studio and use it for something else.

**Example:** my table in the database consists of a field with integer data type, what I want to do in android studio is, if the value of the field =

Comment: the link does not meet my requirement, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best to achieve this is to do some php coding and get your data output as associative array and then

```
json_encode($sqldata);
```

after this I would suggest you to use Volley Networking Library from google and parse the json response in android as per your requirements.